# selectors-api for data attributes

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, selectors-api

In HTML5, CSS selectors seem to operate well with data-* attributes. For example:

```
<style>
div[data-foo='bar'] {
  background:#eee;
}
</style>
<div data-foo='bar'>colored</div>
<div>not colored</div>
```

will properly style the first . But, attempts to select such elements using the selectors-api fail. Examples:

```
var foos = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-foo]='bar'");
```

or

```
var foos = document.querySelectorAll("div data-foo='bar'");
```

in Chrome and Safari, this produces a cryptic error:

SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

Any thoughts on how to use the selectors-api to properly select elements on the basis of data-* attributes?

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for attribute selectors is `[att=val]` so you want `div[data-foo='bar']`.

Comment: Right -- the first one. But, that still give an error message in Chrome. Does it work in any browsers for you?

Answer (score 2):

Anne is right. (Fortunately, as he is one of the editors of the relevant specification.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
div[data-foo='bar'] {
  background:blue;
}
</style>
<div data-foo='bar'>colored</div>
<div>not colored</div>
<script>
var foos = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-foo='bar']");
alert(foos[0])
</script>
```

works for me is Firefox, Opera and Chrome. Note that it's `div[data-foo='bar']`, as you used in the CSS, rather than `div[data-foo]='bar'`, as you used in the script.